# django_channels "Reader at end of file" exception

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I have implemented `django_channels` `AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer` consumer which subscribes to `"chat"` group:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer

class CeleryTaskConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(group='chat', channel=self.channel_name)

    async def new_message_handler(self, event):
        await self.send_json(content={'event': event})
```

Then I regularly send a message to a `"chat"` group:

```
import channels.layers
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

def send_notification():
    channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)("chat", {
        'type': 'new.message.handler',
        'message': 'Hello world!'
    })
```

Everything works as expected, however I regularly get this exception:

```
Exception inside application: Reader at end of file
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 129, in throw
    return self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 59, in __call__
    [receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 129, in throw
    return self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 59, in await_many_dispatch
    await task
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 51, in await_many_dispatch
    result = task.result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 126, in send
    return self.gen.send(value)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 429, in receive
    real_channel
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 110, in __next__
    return self.gen.send(None)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 484, in receive_single
    index, channel_key, timeout=self.brpop_timeout
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 110, in __next__
    return self.gen.send(None)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 327, in _brpop_with_clean
    await connection.eval(cleanup_script, keys=[], args=[channel, backup_queue])
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/commands/scripting.py", line 12, in eval
    return self.execute(b'EVAL', script, len(keys), *(keys + args))
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/commands/__init__.py", line 51, in execute
    return self._pool_or_conn.execute(command, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 319, in execute
    raise ConnectionClosedError(msg)
  Reader at end of file
```

I am not sure what causes it and how to fix it?

I am using Python `3.6.6`, redis server `5.0.4` and these Python packages:

```
Django==2.1.5
aioredis==1.2.0
asgiref==2.3.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
asyncio==3.4.3
channels==2.1.7
channels_redis==2.3.3
daphne==2.2.5
hiredis==0.2.0
msgpack==0.6.0
twisted==18.9.0
```

Comment: did you try `'new.message.handler'` --> `'new_message_handler'`?

Comment: @BearBrown Yup, I have tried it. The `new_message_handler` gets called in both cases. As I mentioned, my example works as expected, however sometimes I get a random error.

Comment: what about this? https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1199

Comment: write this line `await self.channel_layer.group_add(group='chat', channel=self.channel_name)` before `accept()`

Comment: @PankajSharma I have just tried this modification, however it had no effect. I still randomly get the `"Reader at end of file"` exception.

Comment: @niekas Have you resolved it

Comment: @niekas Have you found a solution for this? I've encountered the same problem

Comment: same here, with redis and all python packages up to date.